# Convert accented text into ASCII characters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ascii, transliteration

I would like to convert accented letters and various encodings into the plain English ASCII one in Javascript and wonder what are the possible options. What I need is that:

```
éclair ~becomes~ eclair

bär ~becomes~ bar

привет ~becomes~ privet

こんにちは ~becomes~ konnichiva
```

As you can see the idea is that any language gets converted into the plain English ASCII equivalent. The áčçéñtèd letters are converted into their plain equivalents, letters in cyrillic or japanese encoding are converted into into their transliterated equivalent.

Anyone knows an approach to do that in Javascript?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/remove-accents-diacritics-in-a-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are a number of Node modules that do similar things but are much lighter-weight than node-iconv, and in particular, are in all JS and don't require you to compile any C or C++:

1. [node-unidecode](https://github.com/FGRibreau/node-unidecode) appears to do mostly what you asked for:

   ```
   $ npm install unidecode
   ...
   unidecode@0.1.3 node_modules/unidecode
   $ node
   > var unidecode = require('unidecode');
   undefined
   > unidecode('éclair')
   'eclair'
   > unidecode('bär')
   'bar'
   > unidecode('привет')
   'priviet'
   > unidecode('こんにちは')
   'konnitiha'
   ```
2. [node-transliterator](https://github.com/psyduk/node-transliterator) is even lighter-weight, but behaves even further from what you asked for:

   ```
   $ npm install transliterator
   ...
   transliterator@0.1.0 node_modules/transliterator
   $ node
   > var transliterator = require('transliterator');
   undefined
   > transliterator('éclair')
   'eclair'
   > transliterator('bär')
   'baer'
   > transliterator('привет')
   ''
   > transliterator('こんにちは')
   ''
   ```
3. [node-urlify](https://github.com/Gottox/node-urlify) is slightly closer but also way further from what you asked for:

   ```
   $ npm install urlify
   ...
   urlify@0.3.5 node_modules/urlify
   $ node
   > var urlify = require('urlify').create({ spaces: ' ' });
   undefined
   > urlify('éclair')
   'eclair'
   > urlify('bär')
   'bar'
   > urlify('привет')
   'privet'
   > urlify('こんにちは')
   '_____'
   ```
4. Finally, [limax](https://github.com/lovell/limax) is more heavyweight, when I did `npm install limax` it printed lots of C compiler warnings, but it still just worked and is the closest to what you asked for:

   ```
   $ npm install limax
   ...
   limax@0.0.2 node_modules/limax
   ├── speakingurl@0.9.1
   ├── pinyin2@2.0.8
   ├── hepburn@0.5.2 (bulk-replace@0.0.1)
   └── cld@0.0.6
   $ node
   > var slug = require('limax')
   undefined
   > slug('éclair')
   'eclair'
   > slug('bär')
   'baer'
   > slug('привет')
   'privet'
   > slug('こんにちは')
   'konnichiha'
   ```

Comment: Thanks man, googling node js diacritics gives the inferior libraries with their incomplete list of diacritics; node-unidecode is so much better.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [node-iconv](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-iconv).

Looks like node equivalent of php iconv.

Comment: Please mark your question as "answered" if it helped you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Author here. You may try the [transliteration](https://github.com/andyhu/node-transliteration) module. It can be run in both browser and node.js and with no dependencies